# Can I delete .ibd file in MYSQL .My server storage is rapidly increasing

Tags: mysql

Actually My server storage is rapidly increasing due to the .ibd files in MYSQL.

Can I take backup of .ibd files and delete them.

If yes, May I know the process of doing it, I researched a lot but could not find any solution regarding this.

As, this is production db , I don't want any data loss or down time.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No. You cannot manually do anything with any database file directly. Exception is if its listed in the official manual for the version you are using. If your storage space is increasing, work out the cause. Or acquire more storage.

Comment: yeah. I have checked.the storage is increased due to .ibd files only. the .ibd file is around 256 gb .so, only solution is to increase storage?

Comment: you can't archive data and optimize table?

Comment: And which MySQL version?

Comment: Server version: 5.7.32-0ubuntu0.18.04.1-log (Ubuntu) @danblack

Comment: What kind of data is it?  It sounds like the .ibd will continue to grow regardless of what you do -- other than stop inserting.  I want to look at the possibility of inserting _less_.

Answer (score 2):

**You must not delete an .ibd file** if you want to avoid data loss or downtime. These .ibd files contain your data and indexes. Deleting such a file will result in data loss by definition, and it is also likely it will cause downtime.

You should provision enough storage space for the data you need to keep in your database. Capacity planning is an important task for a database administrator.

You should also decide how much data you need to keep in the database. For example, perhaps data older than 1 year is no longer needed. You can either delete it, or you can export it to files and store for long-term archiving (just in case someone needs to research old data).

You can make a backup using [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html), but the dump will also be large, so you should decide where you can save that dump file. Often a large database server like yours has a second filesystem for storing backups.

I like to use other free backup tools such as [mydumper](https://github.com/maxbube/mydumper) or [Percona XtraBackup](https://www.percona.com/software/mysql-database/percona-xtrabackup).

Once you back up the table corresponding to the .ibd file, you can delete data. The quickest way to do this is [TRUNCATE TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/truncate-table.html). This will empty all rows from the table, and reset the auto-increment id. There is no rollback, so be sure you have backed up any data you want to keep.

Another free tool is Percona Toolkit's [pt-archiver](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-archiver.html). This is a good tool to use, because it works incrementally. It's not good for InnoDB to delete many millions of rows in one transaction. Pt-archiver can delete millions of rows, but it works on a few rows at a time. You can also use pt-archiver to export data to a file, or to copy data from one table to another table. Read the documentation and try it out on a smaller table until you are confident using it.